# Явное преобразование типов в C#

Tags: c#, ооп

Разбираюсь с преобразованием типов. Например:

```
class Person 
{
}

class Student : Person 
{ 
}
```

Неявное преобразование:

```
Person p = new Student();
```

Явное преобразование:

```
Person p = new Person();
p = (Student)p;
```

В этом случае компилятор разрешает преобразование, но при выполнении выбрасывает исключение.

Так когда в C# допустимо явное преобразование типов и как это можно продемонстрировать на данном примере?

Comment: по ходу тут проблема с матчастью

Студент всегда человек, а человек не всегда студент. Как-то так, если на пальцах

Comment: Ну да, это понятно. Вопрос в том: если не здесь, то где можно применить явное преобразование?

Comment: ну дак наоборот же, либо если вы уверены, что p это студент (ну или проверять (p instanceof Student), или как там в дотнете)

    Person p = new Student();
    Student s = (Student) p;
 
Вполне себе нормально ( p = (Student)p; наверно в принципе бессмысленная строка)

Comment: Почитайте [вот этот ответ](http://hashcode.ru/questions/166875#167311).

Answer (score 2):

Явное преобразование типов в C# допустимо в [двух случаях](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/representation-and-identity):

A. Явное преобразование арифметических типов. Пример:

```
double pi = 3.1415926;
int entier = (int)pi;
```

B. Преобразование класса внутри иерархии наследования:

```
Student s = (Student)person; // тут возможно исключение
```

Заметьте, что преобразование между типами, не связанными в иерархии наследования, невозможно в C#:

```
string s = (string)person; // ошибка компиляции
```

Comment: да в шарпе же можно вроде как то реализовать приведение типов или я не прав? помнится на каком-то вопросе давно извращялись

http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/xhbhezf4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: @rasmisha: да, [можно](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09479473%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). Но это не преобразование типов, о котором спрашивал ТС. Хотя синтаксис записи и одинаковый.

Comment: @VladD уговорили :)

Comment: @VladD, большое спасибо.

Comment: @Павел Батищев: пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1):

```
  Person p = new Person();

p = (Student)p;
```

У `p` тип `Person`, вы пытаетесь засунуть туда объект другого типа(`Student`)